# how to use selection cell range variables

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make variable C into the selection cell

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO3Ti.png)
[image]

Dim c= selection area
I tried this code:
ActiveCell.Value
but doesnt' working..
Selcetion cell is always change.. so can't use range(null:null)

```
Sub noname1()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim B As String
Dim C

  B = Cells(20, 87).Value
  C = Selection
  
  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("source.xlsx").Worksheets("5.588")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("dest.xlsx").Worksheets(B)
  
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  wsCopy.Range(C).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
    
  'Optional - Select the destination sheet
  wsDest.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are trying to `Set` a Range, then define `Dim C As Range`, and `Set C = AcitveCell`, even though I would avoid using `Select` or `ActiveCell`

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you for your help! but can you explain for me more? I tried your advise, `Dim C As Range`,`Set C= ActiveCell`, but 1004 runtime error this code:  `wsCopy.Range(C).Copy _` am i miss something?

Comment: Could you clarify which workbook(s) and worksheet(s) are the following three 'items' located in? 1. this code, 2. `B`, and 3. `C`? If you declare `Dim C As Range` then you should do `Set C = Selection` and below `C.Copy`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks to your advice, I solved some problems.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Range" can be a single cell or any number of cells together. Since all cells are on one sheet or another every range is on a sheet as well. A range can't include cells from more than one sheet.

All sheets are in workbooks. No sheet can be in more than one workbook. Therefore no range can be spread over more than one workbook.

To specify a range you need to tell the workbook, the worksheet, its first cell and its last cell. If you don't specify the workbook the `ActiveWorkbook` will be presumed. If you don't specify the worksheet, the `ActiveSheet` will be presumed. Therefore

```
Range("B5:D15")
' is the same as
Activeworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B5:D15")
```

You don't need to select a range in order to copy, clear, delete or modify it. VBA's `Selection` object supports the user's selection on the screen but otherwise largely mirrors the `Range` object which disregards the screen. Therefore, if you select B5:D15 and enter `? Selection.Address(0,0)` in the Immediate pane the answer will be "B5:D15". You will get the same reply if you enter `? Range("B5:D15").Address(0,0)`.

In my example, B5 and D15 are the first and last cells of the range. Excel creates a range name from these coordinates which is presented in inverted commas because it's a string. However, you can also specify the same cells as members of the `Cells` collection (all cells in a range - by default the entire sheet).

```
Debug.Print Range("B5:D15").Address
Debug.Print Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(15, 4)).Address
```

The two lines of code print the same response but the second one is much easier to create using variables, such as changing row or column numbers.

So, now you can see what the code below would do.

```
Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(15, 4)).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)
```